# Inference about a Population(Theoretical)

Tags: self-study, inference, sample

I have this theory question about inference:

[image]

Why can't the answer be **"All female students across all universities"**?
Wouldn't it be more reasonable to apply the generalization to the biggest population possible?

P.S. *If this question is not very relevant to this stackexchange then please tell me, I'll delete it.*

Comment: The only correct answer with the information given is "only the students in the study," which unfortunately is not among the options offered. Any attempt at generalization requires information about how the students were selected for the study.  (Typically, they are bribed or coerced from among students in a particular class and as such only represent themselves.)

Comment: What if it is assumed that the sample was (theoretically) unbiased? Wouldn't then option(b) be more appropriate?

Comment: The problem is that we have little information about which population was sampled.  Biased or not, representative or not, you can't draw any inferences beyond the sample itself until you understand how it is related to the target population.